# What is the replacement to use for `ForSeleniumServer` in Selenium 4.5.0?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I had code like this in a previous version of selenium:

```java
DesiredCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
```

But it is now appearing red as the `ForSeleniumServer` no longer exists:

[image: missing ForSeleniumServer]

What is the replacement for this?

Comment: This was [deprecated](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver/4.4.0/org/openqa/selenium/remote/CapabilityType.ForSeleniumServer.html) in 4.4.0 - and then removed in 4.5.0. This was done in order to make Selenium more (fully?) [W3C compliant]](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/). Hard to prove a negative - but as far as I am aware, there is no replacement for this option - it simply does not exist now. Are you running in incognito mode?

Comment: @andrewJames I was not - but would that help?

Comment: Sorry - that was probably an unhelpful comment/suggestion: I don't know what Selenium used to mean by "ENSURING_CLEAN_SESSION". If there really is no replacement, then just remove the code which no longer compiles and see what happens... (that is the best I can suggest).